# Login to zeppelin issues with docker

Tags: apache-spark, docker, shiro, apache-zeppelin

I've downloaded many zeppeling/spark images and with all of them I have trouble loggin in to the notebooks. This is the shiro.ini file inside the container:

```
    ...
admin = password1
user1 = password2
user2 = password3

# Sample LDAP configuration, for user Authentication, currently tested for single Realm
[main]
#ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm
#ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = cn={0},cn=engg,ou=testdomain,dc=testdomain,dc=com
#ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldaphost:389
#ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = SIMPLE

[urls]
# anon means the access is anonymous.
# authcBasic means Basic Auth Security
# To enfore security, comment the line below and uncomment the next one
/** = anon
#/** = authcBasic
```

Right now I'm using this image: conker84/zeppelin. When I enter the admin and password1 user I got:

```
The username and password that you entered don't match.
```

I've noticed that by inspecting chrome I get:

```
api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I've checked the logs under incubator-zeppelin/logs#, and there's nothing  odd, just the server starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was actually in VirtualBox. I have set up the wrong port configuration in the network port forwarding. After adding a 8080 in both, host and guest, I was able to login to Zeppelin.